# shell to filter prohibited words on a file

Tags: linux, shell, filter, awk

Good day shell lovers!

basically i have two files:

**frequency.txt:** (multiple lines, space separated file containing words and a frequency)

```
de 1711
a 936
et 762
la 530
les 482
pour 439
le 425
...
```

and i have a file containing "prohibited" words:

**stopwords.txt:** (one single line, space separated file)

```
 au aux avec le ces dans ...
```

so i want to delete from *frequency.txt* all the lines containing a word found on *stopwords.txt*

how could i do that? i'm thinking that it could be done with awk.. something like

```
awk 'match($0,SOMETHING_MAGICAL_HERE) == 0 {print $0}' frequency.txt > new.txt
```

but i'm not really sure... any ideas?? thxs in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tr ' ' '\n' < stopwords.txt | grep -vwFf - frequency.txt
```

The `-w` to `grep` is crucial to avoid e.g. `le` in stopwords.txt from removing words containing `le` like `less` or `little`.

Comment: yeap... you're wrigth.. i did needed the `-w`. The awk from @ghostdog74 is working too, but using grep looks cleaner

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)w[$i];next}(!($1 in w))' stop.txt freq.txt
de 1711
a 936
et 762
la 530
les 482
pour 439
```

Comment: @Dan: Rightly said :) +1 to you and +1 to the master.

Answer (score 5):

This will do it for you:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <stopwords.txt | grep -v -w -F -f - frequency.txt
```

-v is to invert the match
-w is for whole word matches only
-F is to indicate that pattern is a set of newline separated fixed strings
-f to get the pattern strings from the stopwords.txt file

If you have trouble with that, because it's space delimited, you can use tr to replace spaces with newlines:

Comment: And throw a `-F` in there too to make it a fraction faster (and avoid problems if any "words" contain `.` or other unusual characters).

Comment: The stop words are in one line and -f expects them to be on separate lines.

Comment: Hmmm... Also, e.g. `le` appearing in stopwords.txt will remove any line *containing* `le` (e.g. `less`, `little`).

Comment: thxs.. it works.. even if the man says that the words on stopwords.txt should be in separated lines
ahh wait.. maybe @j_random_hacker is rigth.. i'll verify that

Comment: You can always also convert a space delimited file to a newline delimited one using tr: tr ' ' '\n' infile outfile

Comment: my bad.. it's not working... maybe it's because of the format on stopwords.txt
@Michael how could i use `tr` and pipe it into grep?

Comment: @Michael: You still haven't addressed the fact that `le` will get rid of `less`, `little`, `inexcusable` etc. :-P

Comment: @michael. You will need the `-w` (or `-o`? ) option as well so you match exact words.

Comment: Updated with -w, thanks j_random_hacker and ghostdog74 for pointing this out

Answer (score 2):

```
join -v1 <(sort frequency.txt) <(tr ' ' '\n' <stopwords.txt|sort) | sort -k2,2rn
```